# How can I run eclipse always as root in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: eclipse, root

When I want to run eclipse in my ubuntu, I have to open a terminal and go to eclipse directory and run "sudo eclipse" command.
That's not so hard but in this case, I have to leave the terminal open, as long as eclipse is running.
Is there any way so I be able to run eclipse as "root" simply by double clicking on it in desktop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want the app to always run as root

```
1) Pin the application to the launcher as normal.

2) Locate the applications .desktop file which will be in either:

/usr/share/applications/APPNAME.desktop
~/.local/share/applications/APPNAME.desktop
or somewhere else, use locate .desktop|grep APPAME
3) Open with gedit:
gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/APPNAME.desktop
4) Change then line

Exec=APP_COMMAND
to

Exec=gksudo -k -u root APP_COMMAND
5) Save
```

This command will also keep your environment which is very usefull if you need to connect to others servers and use your private key.

To add a quicklist option to 'Run as root'

Follow steps 1, 2 and 3 above

If the launcher currently doesn't have any other quicklist options, just append this to the end of the document

```
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=Runroot

[Runroot Shortcut Group]
Name=Run as root
Exec=gksudo -k -u root APP_COMMAND
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Comment: In Step 3), the gksudo is deprecated (since Ubuntu 18.04 LTS). We can use sudo -H instead. And in Step 4) Exec=sudo -H APP_COMMAND

Answer (score -3):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
cd /adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/eclipse
sudo ./eclipse
expect "password:"
send "password\r"
expect eof
```